# woocommerce calculate line total and cart totals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

As you can see in the image, I have a cart that has two products.

Each of the products has some addons. 
The "addon#1" costs 20chf.

If a customer chooses 3 "test product 1" products and adds 2 "addon#1" addons, 
I want to **calculate first the quantity** and **then to add the cost of the addons**.

For example,  in the image, for the first item in the cart, 120 * 3 = 360 and then 2 addons * 20 = 40, 
I want in Total to have 400.
[image]

I tried some actions like   `woocommerce_after_calculate_totals`,
`woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal`,
`woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal` but even if I got the results I want, the total cost of the cart is not the right, it doesn't include the addons.
[image]

```php
function add_addons_to_total_price( $product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $cart ) {
    $subtotal_product_price = 0;
    $product_price = $product->get_price();
    $subtotal_product_price = $product_price * $quantity;
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $key=>$value ) {
        if( isset( $value['total_addons_price'] ) ) {
            $subtotal_product_price += $value['total_addons_price'];
        }
    }
    return ($subtotal_product_price) ? wc_price($subtotal_product_price) : $product_subtotal;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 'add_addons_to_total_price', 10, 4 );
```

Do you have any ideas on how to change the total cost of each item in cart and update the total cost of the cart?

Comment: are you using woocommerce product add-on as woocommerce plugin?

Comment: no, it is a custom plugin